# Electron Tray Icon not working on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, electron, icons, tray

Electron Tray icon is not showing correctly on Ubuntu 20.04 using Electron 13.1.2.

The icon should be the image set bellow:

```
function createTray() {
    const icon = path.join(process.resourcesPath, 'assets/favicon.png');
    tray = new Tray(nativeImage.createFromPath(icon));
    const contextMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate([
        {
            label: 'Show',
            click: () => {
                createWindow();
            },
        },
        {
            label: 'Quit',
            click: () => {
                app.quit();
            },
        },
    ]);

    tray.setContextMenu(contextMenu);
    tray.setToolTip('Desktop Client');
    tray.setTitle('Desktop Client');

    showNotification();
}
```

But it shows a purple icon instead:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6vkl.png)

I used the same path to the app icon and notification icon and it worked (the blue atom icon):
[app icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4iAk.png)
[notification icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTjZ3.png)

It also works well on Windows tray, and I don't know why it doesn't work on Ubuntu.

Here's the image in the project folder [image in folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sE5ao.png)

I've tried to change the image resolution (16x16, 32x32, 64x64, 256x256) but nothing happened.

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you give image path of dist folder, it will work perfect,

```
var tray = new Tray(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/assets/logo.png'))
```